# How to delete the row in struts2 jquery grid from exeternal button

Tags: struts2, struts2-jquery

When I click on the "delete row" button, it calls my jquery function, but it does not delete my row. (please see my below code). I think I am unable to get the row_id with my custom button. That is why I am unable to delete. I do not know what is the solution for this.

### main code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.subscribe('rowdelete', function(event,data) {
        alert("function is calling on the delte button click");
        $("#gridtable").jqGrid('delGridRow',"row_id_s", {height:200,reloadAfterSubmit:true});
    });
    </script>
    <br/>
    <sj:submit id="grid_edit_addbutton" value="Add Row" onClickTopics="rowadd" button="true"/> 
    <sj:submit id="del_gridtable" value="delete Row" onClickTopics="rowdelete" button="true"/>
```

### Full code:

```
<sjg:grid
 id="gridtable"
 caption="List of Subject Details"
 dataType="json"
 href="%{remoteurl}"
 pager="true"
 gridModel="gridModel"
 onClickGroupTopics="rowadd,rowdelete">
    <sjg:gridColumn name="id" index="subjectId" title="ID" formatter="integer" sortable="true" key="true" search="false"  editable="true"  hidden="true" /> 
    <sjg:gridColumn name="subjectName" index="subjectName" title="Subject Name" sortable="true" search="true" editable="true" edittype="text" />
</sjg:grid>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $.subscribe('rowdelete', function(event,data) {
    alert("function is calling on the delte button click");
    $("#gridtable").jqGrid('delGridRow',"row_id_s",{height:200,reloadAfterSubmit:true});
    });
</script>
<br/>
<sj:submit id="grid_edit_addbutton" value="Add Row" onClickTopics="rowadd" button="true"/> 
<sj:submit id="del_gridtable" value="delete Row" onClickTopics="rowdelete" button="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the id in a PROPERTY tag and when you click at the button refresh the datagrid ( by execution the action for ex or refreshing the div that contains it )

Comment: Please explain your answer with little code... It will be easy for me